# Is there an equivalent to Haskell's init function in elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

In Haskell the `init` function returns all the elements in a list except the last element.
For example `init [1, 2, 3]` would return `[1, 2]`.

**Is there a similar function in Elixir?**

I can't find any similar function in the `Enum` or `List` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you like you can also use [Enum.drop/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#drop/2), which Drops the first count items from the collection. *If a negative value count is given, the last count values will be dropped.*

```
[1,2,3] |> Enum.drop(-1) # [1,2]
```

Comment: I'd say the behavior of Enum.drop is closer to the init behavior the original questioner was asking.

Comment: Agreed, `Enum.drop(list, -1)` is the cleaner option here in my opinion :).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [Enum.slice/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#slice/2) providing a [decreasing range](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Range.html) with a negative end:

```
[1, 2, 3] |> Enum.slice(0..-2) # [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always nice to confirm suspicions in these situations, so here's a benchmark comparing the two:

```
Settings:
  duration:      1.0 s

## ListBench
[13:29:22] 1/2: Enum.drop(-1)
[13:29:26] 2/2: Enum.slice(0..-2)

Finished in 7.41 seconds

## ListBench
benchmark name     iterations   average time
Enum.drop(-1)           50000   72.32 µs/op
Enum.slice(0..-2)       10000   273.16 µs/op
```

So yes, `Enum.drop` is the preferred option.